# UIWebview becomes zombies in didReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I have a uiwebview that I connect via IB to my `UIViewController`. 
In the controller.h, I define

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet UIWebView *myUIWebView;
```

I'm compiling for iOS 4.3, so I need the `unsafe_unretained` (otherwise I would use weak)

I've set the delegate of the UIWebView to be the UIViewController in IB.

If the controller gets `didReceiveMemoryWarning` while not being displayed (i.e. I'm on the next screen), the webView is ok (pointing to a valid webView) just before `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]` , and becomes a Zombie right after the call . Is this normal?
I've read that 
Because it is now a Zombie, I can't set it's delegate to nil in the controller dealloc.
So if it is "normal" that it is a Zombie, should I set the delegate to nil in dealloc ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set delegate to nil in `viewWillUnload` or `viewDidUnload` like-

```
- (void)viewWillUnload {
    [webView setDelegate:nil];
}
```

Comment: hmmm... but if I do set delegate to nil in dealloc, it will still be set ... I've checked and viewWillUnload is not called when I 'unstack' the controller (when I'm done with the buying process and go back to main screen)

Comment: oups... If I DON'T set delegate to nil